# Blazor is throwing Null reference exception when trying to filter a list

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I have a list of item that I can filter by brand and if an edit row is open it will save those changes. On initialization, you can filter the list but when you want to change the filter, it throws a null exception. I am not sure what is causing the issue, and being new to Blazor, Its a very confusing error

```
  <MudSelect Value="@_selectedbrand" T="string" Label="Select Brand" Variant="Variant.Filled" ValueChanged="OnValueChanged" >
        @foreach (var item in brand) {
            <MudSelectItem  Value="@item.Id">@item.Description</MudSelectItem>
        }
    </MudSelect>
@code{
 private string? selectedBrand;
  public string _selectedbrand{
        get => selectedBrand;
        set
        {
            selectedBrand=value;
            if(brandTable is not null){
                UpdateBrand(viewModel);

        OnInitializedAsync();
                brandTable.SetEditingItem(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if I remove the `UpdateBrand(viewModel);`,it filters but does not save which isn't user friendly :(

Comment: Why do you call  OnInitializedAsync(); from the setter?

Comment: @DanielW. i was trying to test with it, to no result

Comment: Where did you define viewModel? And where does the Stacktrace from the error point to?